# Localization of a Dedekind Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, dedekind-domain

I have a question [about this article here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/Dedekind.pdf):
In the proof of (ii) of corollary 5.3 it says that $R/P^r\cong R_P/R_P P^r$ where $R_P$ is the localization of a Dedekind Domain R at the prime ideal P. Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Edit: And I also don't really understand why the quotient of a DVR is a PID. I know that DVRs are PIDs and quotients of PIDs over prime ideals are PIDs again but $R_P P^r$ isn't a prime ideal, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi: R \rightarrow R_P /R_P P^r, \ x \mapsto x + R_P P^r$ and $\mu: R \rightarrow R_P, \ x \mapsto \frac{x}{1}$. Then we have

$$ ker(\phi) = \mu^{-1}(R_P P^r) = P^r. $$

By the first isomorphism theorem for rings you get $R/P^r \cong R_P /R_P P^r$ as rings.

Edit:

Let $I\subseteq R_P/R_P P^r$ be an ideal and $\psi: R_P \rightarrow R_P / R_P P^r, \ x \mapsto x + R_P P^r $. As $\psi$ is surjective we have

$$ \psi \circ \psi^{-1} (I) = I.$$

Furthermore, the ideal $\psi^{-1}(I)$ is principal (as $R_P$ is a PID) and thus $I= \psi \circ \psi^{-1}(I)$ is principal as well. What does not hold is, that $R/P^r$ is a PID for $r>1$ (it is not integral, as $(p^{r-1}+ P^r)\cdot (p + P^r)= 0 + P^r$ ) and thus neither is $R_P/R_P P^r$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more thing though: R is not a PID. it's just a Dedekind Domain. Did you mean $R_P$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: It still doesn't really make sense to me. Isn't $\phi^{-1}(I)$ an Ideal in R?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit hasty.